# Add Recaptcha - X-Cart

Tags: php, model-view-controller, x-cart

I am trying to add recaptcha on following page :

> /register.php?main=auth#regdlg

I tried to check

> /skin1/customer/main 
>   /skin1/customer

and some other files in diffrent folder to add Recaptcha code

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="######"></div>
```

but didnt find any page where i can add this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the X-Cart reCAPTCHA plugin or one you have written?

Comment: The one i have written

Comment: It is more cost effective to buy it from X-Cart

Comment: You can buy it here https://market.x-cart.com/addons/google-recaptcha.html